# Get real roots of polynomial by using the bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, matlab

```
y= [0 1.41E-08 1.44E-08 1.50E-08];

fx= 0.0058*x^4-0.0008*x^3+4E-5*x^2-1E-6*x+1E-8;
```

how can I use the bisection method to find the real solution of every (fx-y=0)

---

I tried to find solutions of polynomial with

```
c= [0.0058 -0.0008 4E-5 -1E-6 ((1E-8)-y)]; 
solution=roots(c);
```

with the result

```
???
```

---

I also tried this code:

```
syms x 
y= [0 1.41E-08 1.44E-08 1.50E-08]; 
n=length(y) 
for j= 1:n 
    c=[0.0058 -0.0008 4E-5 -1E-6 ((1E-8)-y(j))];
    solution=roots(c); 
    a=solution(imag(solution)==0); 
    amax=max(a); 
    amin=min(a); 
end
```

giving the result

```
???
```

Comment: Is this academic or some sub-problem of a larger problem? In the latter case, use another solver.

Comment: @LutzL: I tried to find solutions of polynomial
with c= [0.0058 -0.0008 4E-5 -1E-6 ((1E-8)-y)];
solution=roots(c);
I need help to apply the bisection method to find the real solution.

Comment: Each polynomial has two real solutions, around $ -0.00422$ and $0.0805$ for the given coefficients. Thus there is not "The" real solution. -- Please, add your code and the results resp. error messages to your question. -- Also, verify that `c` really is a matrix and that the `roots` command understands matrix input like you intended to use it.

Comment: @LutzL: I wish to use the Bisection method because I wish to find an intermediate positive real solution (fx-y = 0)
I'm not sure I understand the method so I am appealing to you for help because I block
I tried this code:
    syms x
y= [0 1.41E-08 1.44E-08 1.50E-08];
n=length(y)
for j= 1:n
c=[0.0058 -0.0008 4E-5 -1E-6 ((1E-8)-y(j))];
solution=roots(c);
a=solution(imag(solution)==0);
amax=max(a);
amin=min(a);
end

Can you help me please?

Comment: Your method should return the exact solutions, no need to use some weaker method to "improve" the results. Please add to your question why your methods fail.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Bisection you must have a general idea where your solution lies.

You will need an $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a) <0$ and $f(b) > 0$. Then by continuity of f there must exist $x \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

Now define $c$ as $c = \frac{a+b}{2}$. If $f(c) > 0$ then replace b by c, otherwise replace a by c and repeat the process.

You posted some code, but I'm unsure of what language this even is...